# Simple where in Droidparts?

Tags: android, android-framework, droidparts

How to make a simple sql where in another field that is not the primary key, it uses the method where the class manager? does anyone know?

Not found in the documentation (http://droidparts.org) official as still under construction!

Thanks all!

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what you want to do?

Comment: example table products(_id,name,external_id), where find by external_id or select like name. Not found in the documentation example only read by the method which seeks the primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an `EntityManager` subclass:

```
// Select is used to provide data to EntityCursorAdapter
Select<EntityType> select = select().columns("_id", "name").where("external_id",
        Is.EQUAL, 10);
// alternatively, call execute() to get the underlying Cursor
Cursor cursor = select().where("name", Is.LIKE, "%%alex%%").execute();
```

Comment: how can I help in the documentation?

Comment: @claudsan you can fork http://github.com/yanchenko/droidparts.org, add text and then send a pull request. Thanks.